# How to compute $\text{det}((K+D)^{-1}K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Given the eigendecomposition of the positive semi-definite matrix $K = Q\Lambda Q^T$, and a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal elements, is there an efficient way to compute the determiant

$\text{det}((K+D)^{-1}K)$

If not, is it possible to find a good approximation?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked on this site many times. My impression is that there is not yet any efficient method to do "*diagonal updates*" of inverses or determinants, even if the matrices are positive definite. For approximation, if $K$ is sufficiently small, we can use the formula $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\det(I+tX) = \operatorname{trace}(X)$ to obtain $\det(D+K)^{-1}\approx \det(D)^{-1} [1 - \operatorname{trace}(KD^{-1})]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\det ((K+D)^{-1}K)=\frac{\det(K)}{\det(K+D)}$ by Binet formula and, similarly, $\det(K)=\det(Q)^2\det(\Lambda)$ thus $\det(K)=\det(\Lambda)$ if $\det(Q)=1$.

Comment: Since $\Lambda$ is the eigenvalue matrix, $det(K)$ is the product of all the eigenvalues. In fact, my main concern is how to simply the computation of $det(K+D)$.